# Multiple date selecte in single input field?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I want to be a create date picker calender . Which having  option to select multiple dates with single input field . Please help me if someone have do before.

```
 <script>
    var drp; 
    function makedatepicker(){
        drp = $("#myDate").datepicker({});
    }
    function getRange(){
        $("#myOutput").html("");
        $(drp.getDateRange()).each(function() {
            $("#myOutput").append($("<li>").html($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/MM/yy",this))); 
        });
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        makedatepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: please put your date picker code mr. aman

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple date from one input you can use the **datepick.js** Which allow you to select multiple date at a time.

Here is the link for the **[demo](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)** and **[download](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)**

To see the demo for multiple date select click on **"Multiple"** tab on [this page](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

You can select multiple dates using :

```html
<input type="text" id="multi999Picker" size="60" class="is-datepick" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#multi999Picker').datepick({ 
        multiSelect: 999, 
        monthsToShow: 2, 
        showTrigger: '#calImg'
    });
});
```